# Дизайн репозитория на Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-jpa

В задаче по реализации фильтра, столкнулся с следующей проблемой. У фильтра есть некоторое колличество полей, которые в случае если пользователь оставил их пустыми, на сервер, в объект фильтра, прилетают как `null`. А при запросе в базу, мне надо получить объект `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications`, который представит этот фильтр на `SQL` территории. Я хотел использовать следующую конструкцию для формирования объекта `Specifications`:

```
public Page<Phone> list(@NonNull Filter filter) {
    Specifications<Phone> specifications = where(equal("id", filter.getId()))
            .and(isBetween("regDate", filter.getRegFrom(), filter.getRegTo()))
            .and(contain("operatorAccPassword", filter.getOpPassword()))
            .and(contain("operatorAccLogin", filter.getOpLogin()))
            .and(contain("operatorName", filter.getOpName()))
            .and(contain("number", filter.getNumber()))
            .and(equal("status", filter.getStatus()))
            .and(contain("note", filter.getNote()));

    return phoneRepository.findAll(specifications, filter.getPageable());
}

public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Phone> {
    class Specifications {
        public static Specification<Phone> equal(@NonNull String column, @NotNull Object value) {
            return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(column), value);
        }

        public static Specification<Phone> contain(@NonNull String column, @NotNull String value) {
            return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(column), value);
        }

        public static Specification<Phone> isBetween(@NonNull String column, @NonNull Timestamp from, @NonNull Timestamp to) {
            return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.between(root.get(column), from, to);
        }
    }
}
```

Но загвоздка в том, что если в `.and(contain("fieldName", value)` в качестве значения попадает `null`, то соответственно запрос требует `null` в значении соответствующего столбца, для того чтобы считать кортеж подпадающем под условие, а мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы поле просто исключалось из списка условий, если оно равно `null`.

Конечно в самом крайнем случае можно создать отдельный Specifications для каждого поля и наделать кучу if else но хочется сделать нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно выйти из положения имея в виду что на слудующем шаге мне придется учитывать тот факто что таких репозиториев у меня будет много под каждый вид сущьности, не только `Phone` и методы `static Specification<Phone> equal(...)` по сути повторяются.

В общем, буду весьма признателен за любые конструктивные соображения на этот счет.

Comment: А готовые решения тебе не подойдут?: [1](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145/5380322)

Comment: @Cepr0 конечно подойдут просто я так губу и не думал раскатывать. Хотя я удивлен что сам сприн ничего не предлогает, или предлогает но мы не знаем.